# Bad closing bracket indentation for electric-pair in python

Tags: python, doom, electric-pair-mode

I am getting the wrong indentation for closing braces when I use `electric-pair` mode in python.

For example, if I place the cursor (`|`) like so :

```python
for i in range(10):
    foo = [|]
```

and hit return, then I get:

```python
for i in range(10):
    foo = [
        |
]
```

when I would expect to get:

```python
for i in range(10):
    foo = [
        |
    ]
```

Any idea what's going wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: does it happen when you start Emacs with `emacs -q`?

Comment: Nope. In that case you just get a standard new line, since electric-pair's newline command isn't being used

Comment: It works well for me, so plz show your related configuration.